# How to accomplish the requirement by regex

Tags: javascript, regex

There is a string :

```
python php ruby javascript jsonp perhapsphpisoutdated
```

I want to return the words which contain `p` but do not contain  `ph`
Such as :

```
[ 'python', 'javascript', 'jsonp' ]
```

How to write it?

```
 var result = web_development.match(/\b((?!ph)\w)+\b/g);
```

So far, I don't know how to write more, please help me!

Comment: I only want to use one regex, and get the result ;

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
\b([a-oq-z]+|[a-oq-z]*(p[a-gi-z][a-oq-z]*)+)p?\b
```

Explanation: The left part before the OR matches works without a 'p'. The right part first matches an optional prefix without a 'p', then any number of 'p', then something besides 'h', then anything without 'p'; finally an optional 'p' without anything after can occur.

Comment: Did you test it somewhere? I am getting strange results at regexpal.com when using the given string and this regex

Comment: Fixed it. Two things were wrong: Word boundary markers were missing, and the no-p case should still accept an optional 'p' at the end (this is the case where a 'p' is at the end, but NOT in the middle, as in "jsonp")

Answer (score 0):

In python, it can be done like this

```
import re
sample_string = "python php ruby javascript jsonp perhapsphpisoutdated"
regex=r"^((?!ph).)*$"
print [word for word in sample_string.split() if re.search(regex,word)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Choose one of the following approaches:

- the first approach using `String.replace`(to replace words which have `ph` sequence with empty string `""` beforehand) and `String.match` function(to match the rest of words if they contain `p` character):

  ```
  var web_development = "python php ruby javascript jsonp perhapsphpisoutdated",
      result = web_development
                      .replace(/\b[a-z]+?ph([a-z]+)?\b|\bph[a-z]+?\b/g, "")
                      .match(/\b([a-z]+?)?[p]([a-z]+?)?\b/g);

  console.log(result);   // ["python", "javascript", "jsonp"]
  ```
- the second approach using `String.split` and `Array.filter` functions:

  ```
  result = web_development.split(" ").filter(function(word){
      return word.indexOf("p") !== -1 && word.indexOf("ph") === -1;
  });

  console.log(result);   // ["python", "javascript", "jsonp"]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`var reg = /\b(?=\w*p)(?!\w*ph)\w+\b/g;
console.log(web_development.match(reg));`

finally I get the solution... it's hard to work out